# This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (net.skinnycat.accelerometertest.AccelData) [Instantiatable]

how to fix this?

here my code:

```
package net.skinnycat.accelerometertest;

public class AccelData{
private long timestamp;
private double x;
private double y;
private double z;

public AccelData(long timestamp, double x, double y, double z) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public double getZ() {
    return z;
}

public void setZ(double z) {
    this.z = z;
}

public String toString() {
    return "t=" + timestamp + ", x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z;
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

`public AccelData(){}` to your class